# pyQt5: Convert pyqtSignal from float to str

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QObject, that emits a signal as float. What is the most pythonic way to convert this to str for a QLabel.setText method?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel
   
class SerialComponent(QObject):
    value = pyqtSignal(float)

    def loop():
        value.emit(1.0)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("Main.ui", self)

        component = SerialComponent()
        
        component.value.connect(label_display.setText)
```

This will result in

```
TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

What is the most pythonic way to convert this pyqtSignal to str?

Comment: Don't use `findChild()`, uic already creates instance attributes based on the object names set in Designer: your label is already available as `self.label_display`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
component.value.connect(label_display.setNum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Signal has reasonable signature, I'd recomend to modify slot.

```
component.value.connect(lambda value: label_display.setText("{.1f}".format(value)))
```

Comment: Well, there's also [`setNum()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#setNum).